# Open specific pdf files for users

Tags: c#

Sorry but i'm kinda lost here...

So I have database with users and login page, and I want to open specific pdf file for each user after the user login.

for e.g. I have 100 users and 100 pdf file, and let's say user ID"444" logged in then he can see pdf ID"444". ( for him only ).

Comment: Is it a web or desktop application ?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Client side code? Server side code? Logic for getting proper file? Returning file to user? Storing files somewhere?

Comment: web,and i'll store all the files in server.

Answer (score 0):

just get the data from database related to that user and open like below code:

```
   window.open(downloadLink.href,'_blank');
```

greeting:)

Comment: Okay i'll try to add new column with data type varbinary(max) to store pdf files. but how to call it after the user logged in and i'll transfer him to another page then when he click on button he will get that pdf?

Comment: bool val1 = (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User != null) && System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated